# How to create an audio player using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have been given assignment for creating an audio player using js without using any plugin. I am totally blank regarding this can anyone help please. I would prefer to create in firefox...I am not allowed to use HTML5

Comment: I am going to assume you're allowed to use HTML & CSS as well. look up the [HTML5 `audio` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-iframe-element.html#the-audio-element).

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript cannot play audio. You need HTML5 or, usually, Flash.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use HTML5 audio. Here are some links:

- http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/
- http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introduction-to-the-html5-audio-tag-javascript-manipulation/

Comment: Is there anyway to do it with html4